# A question about IEnumerator.GetEnumerator in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a question about the `IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()` method.

```
public class NodeFull
{
    public enum Base : byte {A = 0, C, G, U };
    private int taxID;
    private List<int> children;

    public int TaxID
    {
        get { return taxID; }
        set { taxID = value; }
    }

    public int this[int i]
    {
        get { return children[i]; }
        set { children[i] = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (children as IEnumerator).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public TaxNodeFull(int taxID)
    {
        this.taxID = taxID;
        this.children = new List<int>(3);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, error message says

> 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator' and no extension method 'GetEnumerator' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance

---

Thank you guys. I got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` (or `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`), not `IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()`. The members on `IEnumerator` are `MoveNext()`, `Current` and `Reset()` (and `Dispose` for the generic version). The `IEnumerable` is "something that can be iterated over" (e.g. a list) and the `IEnumerator` represents the current state within that iteration - like a database cursor.

It's slightly odd that your class doesn't implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` itself. I'd expect something like this:

```
class NodeFull : IEnumerable<int>
{
    ... other stuff as normal ...

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Use explicit interface implementation as there's a naming
    // clash. This is a standard pattern for implementing IEnumerable<T>.
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Defer to generic version
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, when will the IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator come to use. If I simply return null in this method, then also i can iterate over the collection using foreach. Do i need it when having a scenario of name clash in implementations and have to implement the interface the explicitly on that class??

Comment: @DnshPly9: You would need it for anything which used the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface instead.

Answer (score 2):

children is `List<int>`, which implements `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable`. The `GetEnumerator()` method is defined for those interfaces, not for `IEnumerator`.

`children as IEnumerator` should result in null.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `GetEnumerator()` method on the [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) interface.  Are you trying to use the [IEnumerABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface perhaps?